# Return a Future variable into a Text Widget Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How would you return a Future widget into a StatelessWidget? I've tried something myself but it gives the error: "type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget?'". Here is the code

```
recieveMessage() async {
var x = 'Test';
  return Text(x);
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: recieveMessage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: No it doesn't sadly :(

Answer (score 1):

you should use the future builder widget

```
Future<widget> recieveMessage() async {
 var x = 'Test';
 return Text(x);
}



FutureBuilder(
 future:recieveMessage()
 builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.connectionState == snapshot.waiting)       
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  
  return snapshot.data
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm getting now this error message: "Another exception was thrown: No Directionality widget found."

Comment: @Teun wrap your whole widget tree with the MaterialApp widget...

Comment: Yes I got it. Thank you